# cifs: mount an entire Samba server

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

There is a Samba server, let's say on `path.to.my.server.com`, with a large number of shared folders. On my Windows machine, I can mount the whole root folder as a disk (`M:\`) and use it like any other partition. I want the same on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Since I need automatic mounting on boot, I edit my `/etc/fstab/`, entering the following:
`//path.to.my.server.com/ /media/my-server/ cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials 0 0`
but get the following error:
`Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address`

Interestingly, I can mount individual shares by
`//path.to.my.server.com/share/ /media/my-server/ cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials 0 0`
but this is useless since I cannot assume what will the server contain at the given moment (and the number of directories is large enough to completely clutter my `/media/`).

Is there any syntax/trick to mount the entire server? I tried omitting the trailing `/` in server path as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305056), but it only gave me `mount error(22): Invalid argument`.

Comment: This is strange.  Could you post your smb.conf file to see how you defined the share?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I do not have the access to it, unfortunately. But I noticed that my Windows setup cannot mount root anymore, so I suppose the problem is on the server side. Therefore I'm considering this question unanswerable.